# NetworkCredentials and Authorization in WebApi

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, webclient, iis-express

I am having a few problems trying to connect to a ASP.NET webapi service (which I am running myself) from a sample console app using WebClient. The webapi is the typical sample site from MVC4:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
}
```

The Controller is decorated with a custom Authenticate attribute:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"localhost\"");
        actionContext.Response = response;
        return;
    }
}
```

The client code is the usual:

```
 var wb = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:64921/Values");
 wb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");

 var aaa = wb.GetResponse();
 Console.WriteLine(aaa);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Now, I know that the `WebClient` or `WebRequest` are supposed to wait for a 401 before sending credentials and that is exactly what I am trying to do here.

Needless to say with the setup above nothing works. I have gone into the IIS express config and changed the following:

```
<basicAuthentication enabled="true" /> (in the security section)
<add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" /> (in the modules section)
```

The problem that I am having is that the 401 gets returned **even before** the server code is actualy hit. I mean that if I stick a breakpoint into the Controller or the Attribute they are not hit. The details of the error are the usual long text about **error 401.2** which I reckon is something to do with IIS configs, but using IIS express and not the nice IIS I do not have a nice GUI to fix this. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IIS config, you have enabled Basic auth processing, so IIS returns the 401 if there are no credentials or the credentials are invalid.

If you want your code to do the basic auth processing, then you need to tell IIS to allow anonymous access.

**EDIT from comments**

If you ask IIS to do basic auth it will check credentials against Windows accounts. This will act before the server code runs, so the Custom Auth Filter will not be hit. In this case the headers returned will be correct and you will see the `WebClient` performing the double request (one anonymous, one with credentials). If the WebClient does not use a computer or domain account (with read permissions on the folder where the site is located), the request will fail.

If you want to do authentication/authorization yourself, you need to tell IIS express not to do any auth and then do it all yourself... this basically means leaving everything as it is in the config (in your case reverting the pieces of config shown in the question) and sending the correct headers, which you already do. If you debug, you will see the Authenticate filter being hit twice, the first time it will be an anonymous that will go inside the if and generate your HTTP 401 Challenge response, the second time it will have credentials in the form of a standard Basic Authorization header: `Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS>`

Comment: How can I do this? Where can IIS get the info that the credentials are valid? I would have to check those against a DB in code anyway. Anyway, it is IIS express here the problem, I cannot find how to get the credentials into my code since it is always sending 401.

Comment: @Tallmaris  I _believe_ if you ask IIS to do basic auth it will check against Windows accounts.  You need to tell IIS express not to do any auth and then do it all yourself.

Comment: @Tallmaris  Just make sure that if you are using .net 4 that you have the 4.0.3 update installed or you won't be able to set the www-authenticate header.

Comment: Ok that starts making a bit of sense... basically the BasicAuthentication in the config validates, as you said, Windows Credentials. Indeed if I use my machine user and pwd I can get through. SO I will need to set up anonymous auth and generate the 401 myself... Just need to see if the WebClient can recognize that and act accordingly (send a second, authenticated, request).

Comment: Bingo, now everything works greatly... thanks for pointing me somewhat in the right direction. :) Do you mind if I edit your answer with all my findings and accept it afterwards?

Comment: @Tallmaris Go ahead. Edit away.